# How does the default .net core controller route "values"?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I'm new to .net core and I don't understand how the default generated Controller which has the attribute

> [Route("api/[controller]")]

can handle action of "api/values"

how did it translate "[controller]" to handle "values"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[controller]` token in the route will be replaced by the name of the controller without the controller suffix at runtime.

If you add a new controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class RockController : Controller
{}
```

Then the `[controller]` will here be replaced by `rock` and the route will then be `api/rock`.

You can read more about *token replacements* [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1#token-replacement-in-route-templates-controller-action-area)